# react - the prop value remain unchanged after parents update corresponding state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are 2 components in my Application, which are `Button` and `Input`
[image]

After I click `Click to update state` button, the value of input with value `May` should be changed to `May New`, but I find that it doesn't happen.

When I check the Input component, the useEffect does not fire.

```
function Input({ inputValue }) {
  // the useEffect does not fire
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputValue);
  }, [inputValue]);
  ...
}
```

How can I solve it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";

import Input from "./Input";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "May"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John"
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {people.map((pp) => {
        return <Input key={pp.id} inputValue={pp} />;
      })}
      <Button people={people} setPeople={setPeople} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Button.js

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ people, setPeople }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        let peopleTemp = people;
        peopleTemp[0]["name"] = "May New";
        setPeople(people);
      }}
    >
      Click to update state
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Input.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function Input({ inputValue }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputValue);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return <input readOnly defaultValue={inputValue.name} />;
}

export default Input;
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-liskov-k8kxin?file=/src/Button.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are mutating the state.

use

```js
onClick = {() => {
    const updatedPeople = people.map((person, index) => {
      // here you check if the person is the one you want to update
      if (index === 0) {
        return { ...person,
          name: 'May New'
        };
      }
      return person;
    })
    setPeople(updatedPeople);
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean that I am mutating the state

Comment: React uses reference equality to understand if that state has been updated. The code `let peopleTemp = people;` does not create a new array and `peopleTemp[0]["name"] = "May New";` does not create a new entry in the array. So react thinks that nothing has changed after the `setPeople` call.

Comment: so `peopleTemp` and `people ` are refering to the same address in memory?

Comment: yes, you could do `let peopleTemp = [...people]` to create a new array, but you are better to create a new object for the updated person too or your `Input` will not know that its `inputValue` prop has been updated. Using `.map` allows you to do both in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `useEffect` in the Input component. It will work.
there is no need of using useEffect.

Comment: changed but still not working
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-liskov-k8kxin?file=/src/Button.js

Comment: updated in sandbox link.

Answer (score 0):

You should do what Gabriele suggested to solve the issue in the console, but you could run in another problem since defaultValue is used for initialization and it won't change even mutating the state. To hack around this you can set a key on the input like: `<input key={inputValue.name} readOnly defaultValue={inputValue.name} />`;